# Preserving Button's Text on Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, ispostback

I can't for the life of me figure this out!  What I want to do is on the first page load set the button's text and the label's text to the current time.  However, when the user clicks the button, only the label's text is updated to the current time and the button's text remains the time of when the page first loaded.  I know I can do this with Ajax but i know there is way to do it just using the IsPostBack method. Can anyone help me?

```
public partial class TestPage : System.Web.UI.Page
```

{

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Button1.Text = "Initial Page Load Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ". (Click to update current time in Label)";
    Label1.Text = "Current Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();





}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a HiddenField to your page, then change your code to;

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ( !Page.IsPostBack ){
        HiddenField1.Value = "Initial Page Load Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ". (Click to update current time in Label)";
    }
    Button1.Text = HiddenField1.Value;
    Label1.Text = "Current Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
}
```

The HiddenField value will be preserved on PostBack so you can set the button text from this.

Comment: Thanks I've tried these methods and they work for the most part but the Button's text changes to "Button" when I click it.  I need the button's text to remain the time of when the page first loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this before setting the text:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
   return
```